# How to cancel action when detect same line in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need PHP code to detect is that line in MySQL database table.
Thanks

Comment: do you mean if a query returns at least one row?

Comment: I mean if in table have same row it will pass (pass: not add to the table) the action.

Comment: please see my answer, hope that is what you were looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from my understanding of your question - in your php code you can do something like this

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
$sqlSearch = "select everything from <table_name> where <column_name> = <value>;";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sqlSearch );
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
// do nothing
}
else{
$sqlInsert = "insert into <table_name> (column1,column2...) VALUES(value1,value2...);";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sqlInsert);
}


?>
```

basically, you want to search the database to see if that row exist and if it does not you want to perform an insert query.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this piece of code, helps you.

```
<?php
    $variable1 = 1;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name='$variable1'";
    $result = $conn->query($query);  //$conn is the connection variable
    if($result->num_rows==0){
        //insert into table if no duplicate tuple doesnot exist.
        $insertquery = "INSERT INTO table_name (column_name) VALUES ('$variable1')";
        $insertresult = $conn->query($insertquery);
    }else{
        //do something
    }
?>
```